# Save fields even if I have a ValidationError

Tags: django, forms, unit-testing

In my `forms.py` file, I have this class that's causing me a big problem :

```
class CustomerBaseForm(forms.Form):
   ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CustomerBaseForm, self).clean()
        bank_account = cleaned_data.get("bank_account")
        ssn = self.cleaned_data.get('ssn')
        bank = self.cleaned_data.get('bank')
        bank_transit = self.cleaned_data.get('bank_transit')

        v = CustomerProfileFormCleaner(self)
        v.clean()

        # The concatenation of bank transit, the bank account and the bank
        # number must be unique. Hence, the following message would be
        # displayed if it is already in use.
        msg = _('The bank, the bank transit and the bank account are already in use')

        customer = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(ssn=ssn)
        qs = FinancialProfile.objects.filter(
            bank=bank,
            bank_transit=bank_transit,
            bank_account=bank_account)

        if customer.count() == 1:
            qs = qs.exclude(customer_id__in=[cust.id for cust in customer])
        if qs.count() > 0:
            self.add_error('bank_account', msg)
            self.add_error('bank', '')
            self.add_error('bank_transit', '')
```

How could I save the fields `bank`, `bank_transit` and `bank_account` even if I have a `ValidationError` and a `forms.Form`? If `ValidationError` prevent me to save the fields, I figure it is possible to force saving them. If not, is there exist a workaround to do that?

I thought I could do such thing inside my class, but it is unclear ..

```
class Meta:
     model = FinancialProfile
     exclude = ['bank', 'bank_transit', 'bank_account']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to perform an action even if you have a runtime error, you can wrap the code that might throw the `ValidationError` in a [try-except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) structure. The page I linked is the official documentation on it, but here's the short version. You put the code that could fail in the `try:` part of the code. Then, after it you can put what exception it might throw. This will prevent the program from crashing then inside the `except:` you can tell your program how to handle it.

Ex.

```
try:
    perform_function(my_dict[my_key])
except KeyError:
    print("I'm sorry the function could not be performed")
#rest of the program.....
```

In the example above, we are passing an element of a dictionary to `perform_function`. If we don't wrap this in a try-except structure, then if `my_dict` does not contain `my_key` our program will crash. Now, however, it will not crash it will print the error message to the user and will continue on with anything else it has to do. So, in your case, you would do something like this:

```
try:
    #part of the program that could throw ValidationError
except ValidationError:
    #Save fields
#continue on with program
```

Hopefully this helps you get started on fixing your problem. I would highly suggest reading that page that I linked, it goes into more depth than I do here.